# bootstrapper fails to install .Net Framework 4.0

Tags: .net, wix, installation, bootstrapper, burn

My installer has .net framework 4.0 and vsto runtime as prerequisites.
But when .net 4.0 is present, my setup is successfully installed.
But when I uninstall .net framework from my system and try to install setup. the setup fails with the following log.

```
 [15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:31]i001: Burn v3.8.1128.0, Windows v6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1), path: c:\users\sheela_rajagopal\desktop\My.bootstrapper.exe, cmdline: '-burn.unelevated BurnPipe.{956F8609-5FCA-49F5-8DFF-097ED45B0F7E} {01593CE2-E143-49AB-AD52-329417E88C80} 5696'
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:31]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\SHEELA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\My._20141230025131.log'
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:31]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'c:\users\sheela_rajagopal\desktop\My.bootstrapper.exe'
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:31]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'My'
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:31]i100: Detect begin, 3 packages
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:31]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client'
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:31]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client'
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:31]i000: Setting string variable 'VSTORVersionV4' to value '10.0.40305'
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:31]i000: Setting string variable 'VSTOMFeature' to value '1'
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:31]i000: Setting string variable 'VSTORVersionV4R' to value '10.0.50903'
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:31]i052: Condition 'NOT DotNetInstall' evaluates to true.
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:31]i052: Condition 'VSTORFeature' evaluates to false.
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:31]i101: Detected package: dotNetFx40_Client_x86_x64, state: Present, cached: None
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:31]i101: Detected package: VSTORuntime, state: Absent, cached: None
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:31]i101: Detected package: WordAddIns, state: Absent, cached: None
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:31]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[15B0:0DB8][2014-12-30T02:51:33]i000: Setting numeric variable 'EulaAcceptCheckbox' to value 0
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:33]i200: Plan begin, 3 packages, action: Install
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:33]i052: Condition 'NOT DotNetInstall OR NOT (DotNetVersion >=v4.0.30319)' evaluates to true.
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:33]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: dotNetFx40_Client_x86_x64
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:33]i052: Condition 'NOT VSTOMFeature OR NOT (VSTORVersionV4R >=v10.0.50903) OR NOT (VSTORVersionV4 >=v10.0.40305)' evaluates to false.
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:33]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: VSTORuntime
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:33]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_WordAddIns' to value 'C:\Users\SHEELA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\My_20141230025131_0_WordAddIns_rollback.log'
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:33]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_WordAddIns' to value 'C:\Users\SHEELA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\My_20141230025131_0_WordAddIns.log'
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:33]i201: Planned package: dotNetFx40_Client_x86_x64, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:33]i201: Planned package: VSTORuntime, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:33]i201: Planned package: WordAddIns, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:33]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:33]i300: Apply begin
[1640:1A24][2014-12-30T02:51:33]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[1640:1A24][2014-12-30T02:51:33]w363: Could not create system restore point, error: 0x80070422. Continuing...
[1640:1A24][2014-12-30T02:51:37]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\SHEELA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{f98a3724-1b98-47a0-aba6-e728cf7e2d3b}\.be\My.Bootstrapper.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{f98a3724-1b98-47a0-aba6-e728cf7e2d3b}\My.Bootstrapper.exe'
[1640:1A24][2014-12-30T02:51:37]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {f98a3724-1b98-47a0-aba6-e728cf7e2d3b}, version: 1.0.0.27
[1640:0D2C][2014-12-30T02:51:38]i305: Verified acquired payload: WordAddIns at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\WordAddIns, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{31774F49-1020-423D-973E-D3DA4D6FE89F}v1.0.0.27\My.SetUP.msi.
[1640:1A24][2014-12-30T02:51:38]i323: Registering package dependency provider: {31774F49-1020-423D-973E-D3DA4D6FE89F}, version: 1.0.0.27, package: WordAddIns
[1640:1A24][2014-12-30T02:51:38]i301: Applying execute package: WordAddIns, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{31774F49-1020-423D-973E-D3DA4D6FE89F}v1.0.0.27\My.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7"'
[1640:1A24][2014-12-30T02:51:52]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
[1640:1A24][2014-12-30T02:51:52]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:52]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:52]i319: Applied execute package: WordAddIns, result: 0x80070643, restart: None
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:52]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[1640:1A24][2014-12-30T02:51:52]i318: Skipped rollback of package: WordAddIns, action: Uninstall, already: Absent
[15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:52]i319: Applied rollback package: WordAddIns, result: 0x0, restart: None
[1640:1A24][2014-12-30T02:51:52]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {31774F49-1020-423D-973E-D3DA4D6FE89F}, package: WordAddIns
[1640:1A24][2014-12-30T02:51:52]i351: Removing cached package: WordAddIns, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{31774F49-1020-423D-973E-D3DA4D6FE89F}v1.0.0.27\
```

[1640:1A24][2014-12-30T02:51:52]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {f98a3724-1b98-47a0-aba6-e728cf7e2d3b}
    [1640:1A24][2014-12-30T02:51:52]i352: Removing cached bundle: {f98a3724-1b98-47a0-aba6-e728cf7e2d3b}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{f98a3724-1b98-47a0-aba6-e728cf7e2d3b}\
    [15B0:13E8][2014-12-30T02:51:53]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070643, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No

```
<util:RegistrySearch Id="VSTORuntimeVersionV4" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4\" Value="Version" Variable="VSTORVersionV4"/>
<util:RegistrySearch Id="VSTORuntimeVersionV4M" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4M\" Value="VSTORFeature_CLR40" Variable="VSTORFeature"/>
<util:RegistrySearch Id="VSTORuntimeVersionV4R" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VSTO Runtime Setup\v4R\" Value="Version" Variable="VSTORVersionV4R"/>
<util:RegistrySearch Id="DotNetTest" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client" Value="Install" Variable="DotNetInstall"/>
<util:RegistrySearch Id="DotNetVersion" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client" Value="Version" Variable="DotNetVersion"/>

<Chain>
  <ExePackage Id="dotNetFx40_Client_x86_x64" SourceFile="dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe" PerMachine="yes" Cache="no"
                   Compressed="no"
                   DownloadUrl="http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/5/A/95A9616B-7A37-4AF6-BC36-D6EA96C8DAAE/dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe"
                   Permanent="yes"
                   InstallCommand="/q /norestart"
                   DetectCondition="NOT DotNetInstall"
                   InstallCondition="NOT DotNetInstall OR NOT (DotNetVersion >=v4.0.30319)" />
  <ExePackage Id="VSTORuntime" SourceFile="vstor_redist.exe" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" Cache="no" Compressed="no"
                   DownloadUrl="http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/0/0/C001737F-822B-48C2-8F6A-CDE13B4B9E9C/vstor_redist.exe"
                   PerMachine="yes"
                   InstallCommand="/q /norestart"
                   DetectCondition="VSTORFeature"
                   InstallCondition="NOT VSTORFeature OR NOT (VSTORVersionV4R >=v10.0.40303) OR NOT (VSTORVersionV4 >=v10.0.21022)"/>
  <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.SetupPath)\My.SetUP.msi" Vital="yes" Compressed="yes" Id="WordAddIns" DisplayInternalUI="yes" />
</Chain>
```

Comment: Do  you have the .Net Installer in same directory?

Comment: I download it from url mentioned in downloadurl property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Burn detected `dotNetFx40_Client_x86_x64` as `Present`:

```
Detected package: dotNetFx40_Client_x86_x64, state: Present, cached: None
```

Burn will not try to install packages that are detected as `Present`.  Remove your install condition, and use the detect condition that the NetFx extension uses.

https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/NetFxExtension/wixlib/NetFx4.wxs

```
<util:RegistrySearchRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40" />
<ExePackage DetectCondition="NETFRAMEWORK40" />
```